# How to transform React's Stateless Component to plain JS?

Tags: reactjs

I was told that the following [react stateless component](https://medium.com/@housecor/react-stateless-functional-components-nine-wins-you-might-have-overlooked-997b0d933dbc#.wp15e2usl):

`({value}) => <li>{value}</li>`

desugars to

`(props) => { var value = props.value; return <li>{value}</li> }`.

I don't really understand the logic behind this sugar.
`(x) => x` is a lambda expression, that I understand. But what I don't understand is : what is `{value}` doing ? My guess is that it extracts the current value of `value` from the `props` which is in scope.

Is `(props) => { var value = props.value; return <li>{value}</li> }` a closure ? Does it close over `props.value` ?

When I pass `({value}) => <li>{value}</li>`  to another function/component, then what will `value` refer to ?

The question originates from [here](https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc#basic-example).

EDIT: this reminds me of reflection, what I mean is, if you were to write something like this in Java then you would need to use reflection... right? - is that a reasonable analogy?

EDIT2:

According to [babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2&code=let%20MyComponent%20%3D%20(%7B%20value%20%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%3Cli%3E%7Bvalue%7D%3C%2Fli%3E%3B%0A) `let MyComponent = ({ value }) => <li>{value}</li>;` desugars to :

```
"use strict";

var MyComponent = function MyComponent(_ref) {
  var value = _ref.value;
  return React.createElement(
    "li",
    null,
    value
  );
};
```

Comment: The `{value}` is object destructuring, and you are right it is pulling the `value` field off the `props` object.

Comment: i think it's more accurate to say that this is pulling `value` off of the object being passed to the function. it just so happens that that object is `props`, because of how this function is used in `react`

Answer (score 2):

This is the form of [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). More specifically the form of it called "Pulling fields from objects passed as function parameter" on MDN.

In this form of descructuring, function pulls necessary fields from the object passed as a parameter. So the function

```
({value}) => { console.log(value) }
```

is indeed desugares into

```
(params) => { console.log(params.value) }
```

is indeed desugares to

Comment: i think the react sugar happens when it transforms `value` into `{value}`, which doesn't happen w/ regular destructuring.  i've never used this sugar myself, but i'm guessing it's something `JSX` does

Comment: @Brandon No, this is pure native ES2015 desturcturing assignment, nothing JSX specific. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Pulling_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter

Comment: in your snippet, yes, but the OP asked about a syntax that expanded into `(props) => { var value = props.value; return <li>{value}</li> }`.  bracketing `value` is not something ES2015 does, so I am assuming it's  JSX.  pure ES2015 would resolve to `(props) => { var value = props.value; return <li>value</li> }`, which wouldn't return valid JSX

Comment: Well of course `return <li>{value}</li>` part is JSX. But this is not the point of the question. But `({value})` part is, and this is pure ES2015.

Comment: from OP: " But what I don't understand is : what is {value} doing ?"